# ASP.NET jQuery error: Unknown Web Method

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

This is my first time attempting to call an ASP.NET page method from jQuery. I am getting a status 500 error with the responseText message that the web method cannot be found. Here is my jQuery $.ajax call:

```
function callCancelPlan(activePlanId, ntLogin) {
    var paramList = '{"activePlanId":"' + activePlanId + '","ntLogin":"' + ntLogin + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ArpWorkItem.aspx/CancelPlan",
        data: paramList,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function() {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(xml,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            alert(xml.status + "||" + xml.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the page method I am trying to call:

```
[WebMethod()]
private static void CancelPlan(int activePlanId, string ntLogin)
{
    StrategyRetrievalPresenter presenter = new StrategyRetrievalPresenter();
    presenter.CancelExistingPlan(offer, ntLogin);            
}
```

I have tried this by decorating the Web Method with and without the parens'()'. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Your web method needs to be public and static.

Comment: Your web method needs to be declared as "static"

Comment: @Max -- correct, it needs to be both public and static, though in this question it already was static.

Comment: I was just guessing that Victor's problem was forgetting the static.

Comment: Note that is not true for web methods in an asmx, where they have to be public and not static. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543347/webservice-unknown-web-method-parameter-name-methodname and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158678/unknown-web-method-exception-when-calling-shared-webmethod

Answer (score 12):

Clean the solution and rebuild. I've seen webmethods throw 500's until you do this.

Answer (score 2):

Add `public static` before your method...

ex.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MethodName() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ajax success:

For me, it was helpful to make:

1. App_Start\RouteConfig

   set
   from

```cs
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

to

```cs
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```

2. make your using method:

```cs
public

static
```

3. add:

```cs
using System.Web.Services;
```

and on top of method using just:

```cs
[WebMethod]
```

is enough

Answer (score 0):

First Of All Don't Forget To Include
using System.Web.Services;

And Make Sure Your Method Should Be Public And Static and avoid adding Multiple Scripts in same Page like jquerymin.js shouldn't be used for every Function/Method in same Page

[WebMethod]
public static sting MethodName(){}

I Had The Same Issue Which Using Ajax And Jquery To Check  Username Exists
Or Not.