# webservice - unknown web method parameter name methodname

Tags: jquery, web-services, asmx, fullcalendar

I called a webservice for fetching items in fullcalendar.
The method is never called and firebug gives this error:

**"POST* [http]://localhost:50536/FullCalendar/ServicioFullCalendar.asmx/GetEventosCalendario
POST [http]://localhost:50536/FullCalendar/ServicioFullCalendar.asmx/GetEventosCalendario

500 Internal Server Error
        1.01s"
"unknown web method parameter name methodname"*

Here is the asmx.vb code:

```
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://localhost/uva/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class ServicioFullCalendar
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    <WebMethod(MessageName:="ObtieneEventos")> _
    Public Shared Function GetEventosCalendario(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String
        Try
            Return CalendarioMensualDAO.Instance.getEventos(startDate, endDate)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("FullCalendar:GetEventos: " & ex.Message)
        Finally

        End Try
    End Function
```

The webservice is "loaded" from the fullcalendar as follows:

```
events: "ServicioFullCalendar.asmx/GetEventosCalendario",
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That was the mistake: the method had to be "not Shared", and without the "Messagename":

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetEventosCalendario(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String
    Try
        Return CalendarioMensualDAO.Instance.getEventos(startDate, endDate)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("FullCalendar:getEventos: " & ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to look at the network traffic and see what's being sent to the service. Then figure out why it's being sent that way.

It seems likely that you really are somehow sending a parameter named "methodname".

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after spending a lot of time realized that the method was marked as protected and not **PUBLIC**. I made it public and it started working.

Comment: I forgot to change my method to static. Once I did that, it started working.