# ajax jquery webmethod private

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webmethod

im doing a call to a webmethod function in the codebehind but i have a doubt..

having the webmethod in the codebehind of a aspx make the function visible for everyone who types the url???

is it possible to use with ajax/jquery a "private" function in the codebehind ???

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/Exemplos", // url da pagina/nome do metodo
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{}", //parametros da função
                    success: function (json) {
                        var JSONObject = json.d;
                        var html = '';
                        for (var i = 0; i < JSONObject.length; i++) {
                            html = html + JSONObject[i].Valorbool + ' - ' + JSONObject[i].Valortxt + '
```

[WebMethod]
public function Exemplos(...)

Answer (score 0):

The webmethod must be public and static.

Similar question: [ASP.NET jQuery error: Unknown Web Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179934/asp-net-jquery-error-unknown-web-method)

If you need more security around your ajax call, try moving it to a web service.