# Why doesn't my ajax call reach my .NET WebMethod?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I can't for the life of me understand why this code isn't working. I need a second set of eyes to review it - TIA:

This function returns success, but the C# method is not called.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    ($("#survey").on("submit", function() {
        var data = serializeForm();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveSurveyInfo",
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        }); //ajax

        return false;
    }));

    function serializeForm() {

        var data = new Object;

        $("#survey input[type='checkbox']").each(

        function(index) {
            data[$(this).get(0).id] = $(this).get(0).checked ? 1 : 0;
        });
        data.otherEnviron = $("#survey input[type='text']").val();
        var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
        return strData;
    }
});
```

**Revised:**

```
    $(function () {
        ($("#survey").on("submit", function() {
            var data = serializeForm();
            alert(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SaveSurveyInfo",
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('ok-'+ data);
                },
                error: function (xml, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xml.status + "||" + xml.responseText);
                }
            }); //ajax

            return false;
        }));
```

**Note:**

```
strData="{\"ms\":1,\"google\":0,\"PHP\":0,\"otherEnviron\":\".NET\"}"
```

**C# WebMethod**

```
[WebMethod]
private void SaveSurveyInfo(int ms, int google, int PHP, string otherEnviron)
{
    using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        scon.Open();
        SqlCommand scmd = scon.CreateCommand();
        scmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scmd.CommandText = "SurveyResults";
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MicrosoftTranslator", ms);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GoogleTranslator", google);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PHPOkay", PHP);
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("other", otherEnviron);
        scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Revised C#**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveSurveyInfo(int ms, int google, int PHP, string otherEnviron)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["C287577_NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            scon.Open();
            SqlCommand scmd = scon.CreateCommand();
            scmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            scmd.CommandText = "SurveyResults";
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MicrosoftTranslator", ms);
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GoogleTranslator", google);
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PHPOkay", PHP);
            scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("other", otherEnviron);
            scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            scmd.Dispose();
        }

    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is still not working. No error msg is shown, only ok.

Comment: Unrelated, don't forget to dispose scmd

Comment: Thanks Alex. After further investigation, the success method shows "Authentication Failed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because WebMethod must be public and static

Similar question: [ASP.NET jQuery error: Unknown Web Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179934/asp-net-jquery-error-unknown-web-method)

If you need more security around your ajax call, try moving it to a web service.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggested, but it still isn't working. Perhaps I should move it to a web service.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void SaveSurveyInfo
```

The method should be static and public in aspx pages to be hit.

In asmx it can be just public.

Comment: I declared it as you suggested but it is still not working.

Comment: @rontornambe I advice to made one little example from some tutorial and see that the service is hit. After that build it for you. One miss thing is attribute [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]